# El tema de generar el comprobante ticket como agrego el codigo Qr

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

[image: ya eh intentado hacer con cuerpo de cadenas y para vizualizarlo se lo asigno a una caja de texto]

```
    void Ticket()
    {
        ClaseTicket ticket = new ClaseTicket();
        ticket.TextoCentro("           Muscle&Fitnes");
        ticket.TextoCentro("           Casa Matriz");
        ticket.TextoCentro("    Mercado Mutualista");
        ticket.TextoCentro("1234567891234567891234");
        ticket.TextoIzquierda("");
        ticket.TextoIzquierda("Comprobante");
        ticket.Igual();
        ticket.TextoIzquierda("gimnasiomusclefitnes@hotmail.com");
        ticket.TextoIzquierda("");
        ticket.TextoExtremo("Caja # 1             ", "ticket # 0111-0001");
        ticket.Igual();
        //Sub cabecera
        ticket.TextoIzquierda("");
        ticket.TextoIzquierda("Atendio Vendedor :" + CodFuncionario.Rows[0][1].ToString() + "  " + CodFuncionario.Rows[0][2].ToString());
        ticket.TextoIzquierda("Cliente :" + " " + t_NombreCliente.Text + " " + t_ApellidoPaterno.Text);
        ticket.TextoIzquierda("");
        ticket.TextoExtremo("Fecha :     " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), "   Hora   :   " + "8;00");
        ticket.Igual();
        //Articulos a vender 
        ticket.EncabezadoInscripcion();
        ticket.Igual();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dg_ListaInscripcion.Rows)
        {
            ticket.AgregarArticulo(fila.Cells[3].Value.ToString(), fila.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), decimal.Parse(fila.Cells[10].Value.ToString()), decimal.Parse(fila.Cells[9].Value.ToString()));
        }
        ticket.Igual();
        //Resumen de la venta. Solo son ejemplos
        ticket.AgregarTotales("          SUBTOTAL", decimal.Parse(MontoFinal.Text));
        ticket.AgregarTotales("          TOTAL", decimal.Parse(MontoFinal.Text));
        ticket.TextoIzquierda("");
        ticket.AgregarTotales("          EFECTIVO ", decimal.Parse(EfectivoTicket));
        ticket.AgregarTotales("          CAMBIO", decimal.Parse(CambioTicket));

        //Texto Final del ticket
        ticket.TextoIzquierda("");
        ticket.TextoIzquierda("");
        ticket.TextoCentro("Gracias por su preferencia!!!");
        ticket.TextoIzquierda("");
        ticket.CortarTicket();
        FormPrueba formprueba = new FormPrueba();
        formprueba.GenerarComprobante(ticket.ImprimirTiket());
        formprueba.Show();
    }
```

*Ahora nose si alguien sabe si hay una manera de hacerlo en Reportviewer y asi ver como poner el codigo Qr se los agradeceria mucho estoy trabajando en C#*
 esto es lo que ya hice

Comment: internamente la clase ClaseTicket que libreria utiliza para generar el ticket? usa la clase PrintDocument

Comment: eh no en la clase ticket se generar en un StringBuilder y  me retorna ese tipo de dato es la unico que pille en la web y esto no me permite agregar un codigo qr debido a que es un cuerpo de cadena o nose como hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente código es vb.Net. Transfórmalo para C#. Hace uso de la librería QRCoder de Raffael Herrmann (https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder). Crea un fichero que puedes incorporar a tu ticket posteriormente. Para esto yo añadiría (si no lo tienes todavía) un método en tu clase ticket que localice una imagen a través de su ruta. La función devuelve la ruta completa del fichero con la imagen del código QR creada.

```
    Private Function MakeQRCode() As String

        Dim stResult As String = String.Empty
        Dim stCadenaQR As String = "Texto a codificar"
        Dim qrGenerator As QRCodeGenerator = New QRCodeGenerator()
        Dim qrCodeData As QRCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(stCadenaQR, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q, True, True, QRCodeGenerator.EciMode.Utf8)
        Dim qrCode As QRCode = New QRCode(qrCodeData)
        Dim qrCodeImage As System.Drawing.Bitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(12)

        stResult = WriteTransformedBitmapToFile(qrCodeImage, "qr")

        Return stResult
    End Function
```